# Twillio SMS Calls Flow

Tags: twilio

I'm writing some code to process SMS from Twilio and I'm not sure I understand the messages flow from the documentation.

**When I initiate a message**

- I use the the TwilioRestClient to make a request
- The request returns synchronously, and I get an SID that I can use to keep track of my message
- I get callbacks to my status callback URL telling me what's the status of the message, which I can identify using the SID I got previously

**When I get an incoming message**

- I process the incoming message and reply with TwiML with my response message
- I **don't** get my response's SID
- Do I get a status call for my response? If I do, how do I know to which of my responses the status belongs?

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the documentation I noticed that there's an [action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#attributes-action) attribute to the message, with the URL used for the callback. So one possible solution would be to assign an internal ID to the response and add it as a query parameter to the callback URL.

Comment: It does make me wonder why I would use the portal callback URL configuration, since this problem makes it useless for half of my use case. It's just confusing.